# ng-dupes when using $http

Tags: angularjs, service

I am trying to explain my complex problem in a simple way so I have made some assumptions which won't affect the problem, I have a service and a controller which i am using for fetching data from a json file like this

```
app.service('getDataService', function($http) {
      var promise = $http({method: 'GET',url:'js/d.json'}).success(function (result) {
              var userInfo = result.data;
              return userInfo;
            });
          return promise;
      });


app.controller("someCtrl",["$scope","$http","$compile","$window","$document","getDataService", function($scope,$http,$compile,$window,$document,getDataService) {
  $scope.create = function() {
        getDataService.then(function(result) {
           $scope.data = [];
           $scope.data = result.data;
        }
        angular.element(document.getElementById("tab")).append($compile("<cust-dir cust-data=\"data\">");
  }
}]);
```

and my HTML view is like this

```
<div ng-controller = "someCtrl">
    <button ng-click = create()>Button</button>
    <div id = "tab"></div>

</div>
```

Where cust-dir is an custom directive in which i am passing "data" and suppose on clicking the button an widget is opening in which i have appended the cust-dir dynamically using $compile.
Every thing is working fine when i am opening the widget first time but if i close the widget and try to open it next time i am getting error of "ng-dupes",
which is arising from the cust-dir template into which i have used ng-repeat to show data on page, I have tried using "track by" but it is showing duplicate data, I think this is the problem related with $http which is adding duplicate data when i am opening widget second time. I have been banging my head over this problem for last week. Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: You don't have to compile the html again n again. The first time should work. When the data update do a $scope.data.length=0; $scope.data.push(result.data);

Comment: You can comment your doubts i will try my best to explain this as much as i can, but help me to solve this one.

Comment: @Chandermani but the controller will run first and then the $http service i have to wait until the data is fetched by $http so i would have to use $compile inside the "getServiceData.then(function(result)) {}".

Comment: You can compile and add directive. When the data is available it will update the view automatically. This is how binding works. On model changed view is updated.

Comment: I have tried putting $compile outside "getServiceData.then()" view is not updating when the "data" changes.

Comment: @Chandermani- View is not updating and also that won't work I have tried to see tha data using console.log its still containing duplicates so even if view would be updated i will still have the same problem.